# The importance of combining a train and inference in Deep Learning

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I thought that the process of training and inference in Deep Learning is separated, however I saw this snippet, and I actually executed the code, I found that my understanding it might be not correct.

```py
network.train()  

batch_losses = []
for step, (imgs, label_imgs) in enumerate(train_loader):
    imgs = Variable(imgs).cuda()  
    label_imgs = Variable(label_imgs.type(torch.LongTensor)).cuda()  

    outputs = network(imgs)  

    loss = loss_fn(outputs, label_imgs)
    loss_value = loss.data.cpu().numpy()
    batch_losses.append(loss_value)
```

I point out `outputs = network(imgs)` to figure out this procedure. this is typically used for estimating model? I know that estimating model is quite good to see our direction. but I don't understand that it's necessary. If I want to boost my training time, could I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet you shared is actually just the training code for a deep learning model. Here, the `outputs = network(imgs)` actually takes in the **imgs** i.e; the **training data** and gives the **predicted outputs** after passing through the **network (the model you want to train your data on).**

And then based on that outputs, loss_fn is calculated here `loss = loss_fn(outputs, label_imgs)` taking the predicted labels **(outputs)** and the actual labels **(label_imgs)**

**Note:** In the inference, you dont generally calculate the loss, you calculate the accuracy of the predicted labels. Loss is calculated only on the training data to measure if the training is happening properly and if the loss is decreasing.
I suggest you once go through some basic deep learning tutorials to get a better insight in case you still have some doubts.

Comment: It's assumed. I didn't notice that fact you mentioned in Note. It's just basic knowledge, but It helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I would just like to point out '*inference*' just means: computing the output based on some data points. It has nothing to do with what you make of it (whether it is for accuracy measures, optimization of the model, validation, etc...).